# Old podcast episodes

Tags: support, podcast

iTunes only lets me get the last 10 episodes of the Stack Overflow podcast.  If I wanted to get some of the older ones onto my iPod, what are my options?

I can get the MP3s by clicking one-at-a-time on the "Download" link on the episode pages at http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/.  Further, I believe that with some [MP3 tagging magic](http://markbowers.org/blog/node/185#comment-4049) I could mark them as podcasts, and not audio files.

Before I go writing a script to do this, is there a trivial way - say, an RSS feed of *all* the episodes, with the descriptions, etc, to get the back catalogue?

(Windows/Cygwin-friendly answers are preferred.)

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Not yet; haven't had the time to investigate sorry.

Comment: It would be nice if someone could put all of the old episodes into a torrent and upload maybe....volunteers? :)

Comment: If you read the feed with google reader, you can get all the episodes. So it seems it's a problem with iTunes

Comment: http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/5044115

Comment: Related: "Where can I get all the Stack Overflow podcasts in one click?", http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14453

Comment: I posted a one-line solution for lazy people here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/234121/183776

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may work...

Episodes 1 through 63 inclusive of Stackoverflow.com podcasts in mp3 format:
http://thepiratebay.org/torrent/5044115

Comment: It's actually completely legal to redistribute all the podcasts (so long as the conditions for http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-sa/3.0/us/ are met) so it's a little funny to see them up on TPB. The least you could have done was put in a README with attribution and the CC license...

Comment: The conditions weren't met I guess, so hence, ThePirateBay!  lol

Comment: PIRATES! YARRRRRrrrr!!

Answer (score 6):

```
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-001.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-002.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-003.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-004.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-005.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-006.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-007.mp3
http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-008.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-EpisodeNine-2008.06.10.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode010-2008.06.18.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode011-2008.06.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode012-2008.07.01.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode013-2008.07.08.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode014-2008.07.15.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode015-2008.07.22.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode016-2008.07.29.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode017-2008.08.12.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode18-2008.08.19.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode19-2008.08.26.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode20-2008.09.02.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.09.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.16.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode23-2008.09.23.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode24-2008.09.30.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode25-2008.10.07.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode26-2008.10.14.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode27-2008.10.28.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode28-2008.11.04.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode29-2008.11.11.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode30-2008.11.18.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode31-2008.11.25.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode32-2008.12.02.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode33-2008.12.10.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode34-2008.12.16.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode35-2008.12.30.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode36-2009.01.06.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode37-2009.01.13.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode38-2009.01.20.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode39-2009.01.29.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode40-2009.02.03.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode41-2009.01.10.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode42-2009.02.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode43-2009.02.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode44-2009.03.03.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode45-2009.03.10.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode46-2009.03.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode47-2009.03.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode48-2009.04.07.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode49-2009.04.14.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode51-2009.04.28.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode52-2009.05.05.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode53-2009.05.12.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode54-2009.05.20.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode55-2009.05.26.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode56-2009.06.02.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode57-2009.06.09.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode58-2009.06.16.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode59-2009.06.23.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode60-2009.06.30.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode61-2009.07.14.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode62-2009.07.21.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode63-2009.07.28.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode64-2009.08.04.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode65-2009.08.11.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode66-2009.09.01.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode67-2009.09.08.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode68-2009.09.15.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode69-2009.09.29.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode70-2009.10.13.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode71-2009.10.19.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode72-2009.10.28.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode73-2009.11.06.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode74-2009.11.10.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode75-2009.11.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode76-2009.11.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode77-2009.12.08.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode78-2009.12.15.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode79-2010.01.05.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode80-2010.01.19.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode81-2010.01.26.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode82-2010.02.02.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode83-2010.02.09.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode84-2010.02.16.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode85-2010.03.09.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode86-2010.03.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode87-2010.04.15.mp3
```

---

copy that list into `so_podcasts.txt` and run:

```
cat so_podcasts.txt | while read i; do wget $i; done
```

Comment: [The first 7 are broken now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/where-are-the-first-7-episodes-of-the-stack-overflow-podcast/315377#315377)

Answer (score 4):

Go to https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/ - you can go back as far as you like and download them that way.

Comment: Gives me the sames files as browsing through the IT Conversations site.  The more pressing issue is that the MP3s come through as songs (or at best, audiobooks) rather than podcasts, when they get into iTunes.

Comment: Is this just a matter of tagging? Does iTunes recognise a specific Genre tag (or similar) for podcasts? If so, it should be easy to apply that to the mp3s.

Comment: It does - see the "MP3 tagging magic" link in the question - but I had hoped that someone had done this (possibly including the episode synopsis) already.  Perhaps I have to be the one to do this!

Comment: I suggest subscribing to the "podcast only" RSS feed using Google Reader and then you can more easily navigate, search, and download  older episodes.

(see @Juan Manuel's response- http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/old-podcast-episodes/6962#6962)

Comment: It works (even in 2019), though there is [an issue with the sound quality when listening in the browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/where-are-the-first-7-episodes-of-the-stack-overflow-podcast/315377#315377) on SoundCloud for at least the first episodes, e.g. [the very first one](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/17/podcast-1/). Download is the workaround.

Answer (score 2):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast

Comment: Also only has the last 10, it seems.

Comment: @Ian Elliot- If you use something like Google Reader and scroll down, it retrieves *all* of the episodes including the first one.

Answer (score 2):

I have found a feed that goes back as far as Episode 33 (which, seeing as we are at 62 today, is 30 eps).

http://rss.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.xml

I will contact them to see if there is a way to go back further.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [DownThemAll](http://www.downthemall.net/) Firefox extension, and setting filtering in `*.mp3` or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

The list of download URLs for episode 8 to episode 79 are listed below. Using a text editor in block mode and [Wget](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget) (or similar) it should not take more than a few minutes to create a script on Windows, Linux or Mac OS X that can start downloading all the available podcasts.

```
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode8-2008.06.03.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-EpisodeNine-2008.06.10.mp3

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode010-2008.06.18.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode011-2008.06.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode012-2008.07.01.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode013-2008.07.08.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode014-2008.07.15.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode015-2008.07.22.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode016-2008.07.29.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode017-2008.08.12.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode18-2008.08.19.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode19-2008.08.26.mp3

http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode20-2008.09.02.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.09.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.16.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode23-2008.09.23.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode24-2008.09.30.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode25-2008.10.07.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode26-2008.10.14.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode27-2008.10.28.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode28-2008.11.04.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode29-2008.11.11.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode30-2008.11.18.mp3

http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode31-2008.11.25.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode32-2008.12.02.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode33-2008.12.10.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode34-2008.12.16.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode35-2008.12.30.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode36-2009.01.06.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode37-2009.01.13.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode38-2009.01.20.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode39-2009.01.29.mp3

http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode40-2009.02.03.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode41-2009.01.10.mp3
http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode42-2009.02.17.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode43-2009.02.24.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode44-2009.03.03.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode45-2009.03.10.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode46-2009.03.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode47-2009.03.24.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode48-2009.04.07.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode49-2009.04.14.mp3

http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode51-2009.04.28.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode52-2009.05.05.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode53-2009.05.12.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode54-2009.05.20.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode55-2009.05.26.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode56-2009.06.02.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode57-2009.06.09.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode58-2009.06.16.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode59-2009.06.23.mp3

http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode60-2009.06.30.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode61-2009.07.14.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode62-2009.07.21.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode64-2009.08.04.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode63-2009.07.28.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode65-2009.08.11.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode66-2009.09.01.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode67-2009.09.08.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode68-2009.09.15.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode69-2009.09.29.mp3

http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode70-2009.10.13.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode71-2009.10.19.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode72-2009.10.28.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode73-2009.11.06.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode74-2009.11.10.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode75-2009.11.17.mp3
http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode76-2009.11.24.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode77-2009.12.08.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode78-2009.12.15.mp3
http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode79-2010.01.05.mp3
```

Comment: The redirect links don't work. See my answer with the corrected ones

Comment: @Toad: which one did you try? I just tested http://www.podtrac.com/pts/redirect.mp3/cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode017-2008.08.12.mp3 and it worked for me. Anyway there is a list at https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4 with all 87 episodes, including the first 7 episodes.

Comment: Maybe it's just curl which couldn't handle the indirections. Thanks for pointing me to the earlier episodes...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the list with a Bash script (tested on Mac). The other episodes it doesn't seem to download. Does anyone have URLs of the older ones?

```
#!/bin/bash
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode017-2008.08.12.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode18-2008.08.19.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode19-2008.08.26.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode20-2008.09.02.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.09.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode21-2008.09.16.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode23-2008.09.23.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode24-2008.09.30.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode25-2008.10.07.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode26-2008.10.14.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode27-2008.10.28.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode28-2008.11.04.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode29-2008.11.11.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode30-2008.11.18.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode31-2008.11.25.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode32-2008.12.02.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode33-2008.12.10.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode34-2008.12.16.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode35-2008.12.30.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode36-2009.01.06.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode37-2009.01.13.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode38-2009.01.20.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode39-2009.01.29.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode40-2009.02.03.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode41-2009.01.10.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode42-2009.02.17.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode43-2009.02.24.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode44-2009.03.03.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode45-2009.03.10.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode46-2009.03.17.mp3
curl -C – -O http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode47-2009.03.24.mp3
curl -C – -O http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode48-2009.04.07.mp3
curl -C – -O http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/audio/download/ITC.SO-Episode49-2009.04.14.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode50-2009.04.21.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode51-2009.04.28.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode52-2009.05.05.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode53-2009.05.12.mp3
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode54-2009.05.20.mp3    
curl -C – -O http://cdn.conversationsnetwork.org/ITC.SO-Episode55-2009.05.26.mp3
```

Comment: All 87 episodes are listed at https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4, including the first 7.