# Where can I get all the Stack Overflow podcasts in one click?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, podcast, downloads

Where can I get all the Stack Overflow podcasts in one click?

Comment: Related: "Old podcast episodes", http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/category/podcasts/

Of course you need more than one click to go back in time to the older ones.

Comment: This also includes all of the photos and extra stuff from the podcast posts on the blog.  If all you want is the text and link to audio use the link I found: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast

Comment: Please note that blog podcast has been moved to: http://blog.stackexchange.com/category/podcasts/feed/

Comment: The link is broken - "Page not found"

Answer (score 3):

Why not download the first (or latest) one, then download the rest while you start listening to it? Personally I'd probably just do it manually rather than bothering with an autodownloader... do you really need more than about 10 hours' worth to start with?

Comment: If Jon Skeet says so.

Answer (score 2):

Joel posted the feed link on [his blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/04/22.html) a while back which is https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast

Comment: Only shows the last 10 postings, though...

Comment: Not true!! If you add the feed to Google Reader...you'll see that you can scroll through every episode from day one to now. So it seems whatever you're using to read the feed, lacks the feature to go past ten posts.

Comment: I was looking at the raw XML, thinking about parsing it from a programmatic perspective to find and extract the MP3 files.

Comment: I have all the entries for SO blog here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21288/index-for-all-the-entries-of-blog-stackoverflow-com  They don't fit in the question length though SO, there will not be room for the subsequent

Answer (score 0):

The [IT Conversations StackOverflow RSS feed](http://rss.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.xml)
contains the last 30 podcasts.  (currently #39 - #68, Jan. - Sept. 2009)