# Download all StackOverflow podcasts in archive

Tags: support, podcast, downloads

Can I download all podcasts in one archive somewhere?

Just want to listen at commute time.

Comment: Have you considered a job with a much shorter commute?

Comment: duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14453/where-can-i-get-all-the-stack-overflow-podcasts-in-one-click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered an easy way to download all of the episodes in bulk. You just need youtube-dl (command line media downloader available for Linux, Windows, Mac). Then it's just a matter of running `youtube-dl http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/sets/stack-overflow-podcasts-1/` and the whole set will be downloaded. The first couple of episodes will have a wrong file extension, so it may be necessary to change it to `.mp3`.

For Stack Exchange Podcast, use `youtube-dl http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/sets/stack-exchange-podcasts/ http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-28`

(Episode 28 is missing from the list, so it needs to be downloaded explicitly)

Alternatively, gPodder (and possibly many other podcast managers) can download the entire RSS feed at once, although earlier episodes are missing.

Answer (score 7):

You can take them from [the source](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/) - the host of all the actual files.

Looks like they even got [sets of podcasts](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/sets) and you can also subscribe to the [RSS fee](http://feeds.soundcloud.com/users/4273388-stack-exchange/tracks)d.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you don't want to download ALL the 118 or so existing podcasts? If so you may have to download them individually.

Follow the official [Soundcloud](http://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/) page for the podcast. Podcasts can either be streamed or downloaded.

Subscribe to the podcasts hosted on [iTunes](http://itunes.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-exchange-podcast/id279215411), which include up to ten of the most recent podcasts that can be downloaded. Podcasts can be set up to be automaticaly downloaded to your computer or digital device.

Comment: I want all 118 files in one archive as I wrote in topic. The size of the file doesn't matter.