# RSS feed for all podcast episodes

Tags: support, feed, podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Old podcast episodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/old-podcast-episodes)

Where can I find an RSS feed of all the Stack Overflow podcast episodes, and not just the latest 10?

Comment: See answers here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/old-podcast-episodes

Comment: I saw that, but it doesn't answer my question. I think the only person who can answer it is Jeff Atwood. He is the only one who could create such a feed...