# A timely and complete feed for the podcast?

Tags: podcast, support

Suffering from podcast withdrawal (where is 74?), I have sought refuge in the archives.

But my iTunes seems broken. I have every episode except #1 and 2. Here's my URL:

- https://blog.stackoverflow.com/?feed=podcast

Is there any way to get iTunes to "find" those earlier episodes? Is there a feed out there with *every* episode that gets updated on a timely basis (I click refresh on IT Conversations every 5 mins)?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/old-podcast-episodes

Answer (score 1):

Go to [blog.stackoverflow.com](https://blog.stackoverflow.com) and just search for them.  They're all there, including episodes [1](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-1/) and [2](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-2/).  I don't think netcast aggregaters like iTunes are concerned with keeping an archive of everything ever posted.  They only care about what's new.  If you want that history, you have to go to the source.

Answer (score 0):

Can't remeber where I saw it, but I seem to remember the feeds only show but so far back. Frankly I'm surprised the SO feed goes that far back. Most shows only go 5 - 10 episodes back.

Comment: The feed only has 5 episodes or so. My iTunes just has a record over the last year. But I subscribed *after* 1&2 were *not* listed. :-(

Answer (score 0):

A google search for "stack overflow podcast N" turned up:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-1/
https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/04/podcast-2/