# Where are the first 7 episodes of the Stack Overflow podcast?

Tags: support, podcast

Is it possible to get hold of the first 7 episodes of the Stack Overflow podcast?

The page with [podcast 1-10](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html?series=&channel=&offset=71) on ITConversations only lists episode 8 and 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All of the podcasts are now on SoundCloud](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/tracks), all the way back to 2008 (the https://blog.stackoverflow.com links are broken now).

Sample: [Episode 1, 2008-04-16](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-77).

But note that the sound quality is close to unbearable if using the webpage to listen to one of the first episodes. The trick is to download the MP3 file and play it through some media player.

Download requires registration and log in to SoundCloud - the option *"Download"* only appears in <kbd>... More</kbd> if logged in.

Comment: Hello ... out of curiosity: what is that new (?) enhanced nickname about?

Comment: @GhostCat: Stack Overflow (the company) forgetting about the *very* extensive research (by the founders) and experience (also by the founders, of Usenet, BBSes, and horrible forums), including the writings of Clay Shirky (e.g. *"[A Group Is Its Own Worst Enemy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-group-is-its-own-worst-enemy/)"*), that went into the design of Stack Overflow. In other words, they are bound to repeat all the mistakes of the past (before Stack Overflow, before 2008) if they are not careful.

Comment: The audio quality problems using a web browser with SoundCloud seem to be have been fixed (tested with [episode 5](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-73) on [Ubuntu MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_MATE) (Focal Fossa) with [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)) and [Firefox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Firefox)).