# The game theory model behind Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, user-experience, business-model

Where or how (and if, of course) is it possible to see the [game theory model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory) behind Stack Exchange, the one responsible for user motivation and improvement? How was it built? Is it frequently tested and updated?

Comment: slightly similar. you refer to another question tgat was flagged duplicate, where the latter asks about history. I wonder about the game theory and the user motivation model

Comment: Agreed, not a duplicate.

Comment: Define gameplay ...

Comment: [What motivates people to answer questions in Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/3742)

Comment: semi duplicate, it close but not it... less history or rules, I was wondering about the actual model, ubder the condition that it is not a sercet or something like that

Comment: @DavidPostill game theory... decision tree/ simoltanious game  that maps the dynamics of the site

Comment: It is well explained in the referenced podcasts (a little long, but unlike more recent podcasts they are not content-free (as Scott Hanselman once put it)).

Comment: @PeterMortensen Ok. I'll listen then

Comment: On the other duplicate: The answer was written by a self-declared troll (that statement is no longer on the public Internet)

Comment: The first 7 episodes were always hard to get (they were not posted on *IT Conversations*). At some point the first one was at http://blog.stackoverflow.com/audio/stackoverflow-podcast-001.mp3, but that is no longer the case.

Comment: Related (but as stated, the links are all broken now): *[Where are the first 7 episodes of the Stack Overflow podcast?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36254)*

Comment: The first 87 episodes are in this list, but again with the same problem for the first 7: [show notes and transcriptions for the Stack Overflow podcast.](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4)

Comment: OK, [I found a place with the first seven episodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/where-are-the-first-7-episodes-of-the-stack-overflow-podcast/315377#315377)!!!! (All of the several hundred postcasts, in fact.) Do pay attention to the note about downloading.