# Where can I listen to old Jeff and Joel SO podcasts from 2008-2011?

Tags: support, podcast

I used to listen to them long time ago, and found great value in them, as Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky discussed various technical practical topics while building Stack Overflow. They were highly technical, useful, interesting, and really, really funny.

I thought I should listen to them again, and went to iTunes, but they are not there anymore. First episode on iTunes starts from 2011, when the podcast relaunched. I looked at the podcast [website](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/04/23/podcast-2/), and they are there, but I don't see an option to play them.

It would be a real tragedy if Stack Overflow decided to remove them from the site entirely; only because sometimes, they were politically inaccurate.

**Where can I listen to the old Jeff and Joel podcasts from 2008-2011?**

Comment: Re *"First episode on iTunes starts from 2011"*: Are you sure it is not because of wrong timestamping (at least at SoundCloud - e.g. the [very first podcast episode](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-77) is timestamped 2011-04-20, but it was actually published 2008-04-14)?

Comment: To reduce confusion, Stack Overflow ought to correct the timestamps. And perhaps add a series/order designation to each podcast (e.g., "(series 1)", "(series 2)", "(series 3)").

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The old episodes are still available on SoundCloud: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange

For example, here's a link to episode #2: https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-76

The layout of Stack Overflow blog has changed many times and now old posts don't have a valid link to the podcast anywhere in them.

P.S. If you really care so much about the old episodes perhaps it makes sense to back them up somewhere just in case.

Comment: Yes, but it is a very long list (and the newer restarts (plural) of the podcast make it confusing by nearly identical titles)) and infinite scroll makes the more annoying. And lost timestamps (for instance, the [very first one](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-77) is timestamped 2011-04-21, but it is from 2008)).

Comment: For the sound quality problems for some of the podcasts on SoundCloud (e.g., the [very first one](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-podcast-77), 2008), [there is a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36254/where-are-the-first-7-episodes-of-the-stack-overflow-podcast/315377#315377).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q Thank you for your comment. I always download MP3 to listen on 2X speed, that's why didn't notice the quality issues.

Answer (score 2):

I recently found the podcasts have been added back to the Stack Overflow podcasts on [Apple Podcasts](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/the-stack-overflow-podcast/id1033688462). Thank you, Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 2):

They are in Spotify as well. They have a channel in https://open.spotify.com/show/0e5eoM6w7eW9Wu7wMA04Tr?si=WYr9Qgc7SuCvOMzHWQ2d8Q.

For example, in https://open.spotify.com/episode/5QyMww6pfppZ5QmA2ujuG1?si=WrV6tWawSJCVMXl8n2tLDA you can find the very first episode.

Comment: But the very first episode also has an incorrect timestamp (April 2011) at Spotify. It is about three years older (published 2008-04-14)

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q yes, in fact the order is not correct. I reported it in [The episode #35 of the Podcast shows as the first one in Spotify](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346074/209901)