# The episode #35 of the Podcast shows as the first one in Spotify

Tags: bug, podcast

I was browsing through the Spotify channel of [The Stack Overflow Podcast](https://open.spotify.com/show/0e5eoM6w7eW9Wu7wMA04Tr?si=6k4M_iTyT2yA2IV-mPloXA#upsell) to go the origins. Using the app of Spotify I went down to the beginning of times and found out that the order is a bit strange:

- ...
- Stack Exchange Podcast - Episode #03 w/ Jon Skeeet - May 11, 2011
- Stack Exchange Podcast - Episode #03 w/ Scott Hanselman - May 4, 2011
- Stack Exchange Podcast - Episode #02 - Apr 20, 2011
- Stack Exchange Podcast - Episode #01 - Apr 20, 2011
- Stack Overflow Podcast - Episode #87 - Apr 20, 2011
- ... #86, #85... all the way to #3 without #35, and
- Stack Overflow Podcast - Episode #02 - Apr 20, 2011
- Stack Overflow Podcast - Episode #01 - Apr 20, 2011
- **Stack Overflow Podcast - Episode #35 - Jan 1, 2009**

That is, the oldest one is the episode #35, dated on Jan 1, 2009, while the range from the 1st to the 87th (without #35) are all dated on Apr 20, 2011.

Could it be possible to date the 35th episode to Apr 20, 2011 as well, so it shows in the proper order?