# How can I control the number of podcast RSS feed entries on stackowerflow?

Tags: discussion, podcast

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Old podcast episodes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6960/old-podcast-episodes)

The [default](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/index.php?feed=podcast) URL gives me only the 10 newest podcasts. How can I get a lengthier list? Or list all of the podcasts?

Comment: -1 as not programming related. I don't know where you should ask this though.

Comment: Hmmm, you are right. It is easy to re-formulate my question.

What is the argument list of the podcast feed query function?

A bit closer to programming this way ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are also hosted at [IT Covnersations](http://itc.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.html), providing also an [RSS link](http://rss.conversationsnetwork.org/series/stackoverflow.xml) (though only episodes 21-51 atm).

Answer (score 2):

Transcript wiki has a list of [all podcasts](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4), though it lacks an RSS feed to subscribe to.